# Boolean Logic Equation

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How can I prove this. what is the way? im up to the second last line. and i dont actually know how can x * (1 + y) then the y just disappears into x * 1.

```
x + x * y = x
x + x * y = (x * 1) + (x * y)
          = x * (1 + y)
          = x * 1 [THIS LINE]
          = x
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations) we have:

\begin{align*}
a \cdot b &= \min{(a,b)}\\
a + b &= \max{(a,b)}
\end{align*}

---

So, by the first definition it's obvious that:

$$ x \cdot 1 = \min{(x,1)} = x$$

Since $x \leq 1$.

By the same reasoning:

$$1 + y = \max{(1,y)} = 1$$
since $y \leq 1$.

So you have:

\begin{align*}
x + x \cdot y &= (x \cdot 1) + (x \cdot y)\\
&= x \cdot \color{red}{(1 + y)}\\
&= x \cdot \color{red}{1}\\
&= x \cdot 1 = x
\end{align*}